# How do I dynamically construct an ajax url action string on Razor page?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core, razor

I'm building an Asp.NetCore app using Razor pages.
I am trying to create a generic to construct Url actions within the page.

Ideally I want to create a javascript function that I can share across multiple pages.

**Consider the following Javascript function:**

```
Function Foo( actionName, entityType) {
    
    // This is what I'd like the result to be....
    // var urlAction = "'@Url.Action("DeleteCompany","Company")'";
    var urlAction = "'@Url.Action(""" + actionName + entityName + """,""" + entityName """)'""";

    var result = DevExpress.ui.dialog.confirm("message", "title");  
    result.done(function (dialogResult) {
        $.ajax({
            url: urlAction,
            data: { companyId: entityId },
            type:"Post",
            success: function () {
            }
        });
    });
```

I would like to be able to dynamically construct my urlAction string so I can make use it generically
across the razor pages in my app.

Is it possible to do that?
If so, how do I correctly construct the urlAction string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to create js function which can be shared across multiple pages. To acheive this goal, you need **create this function in external js file**. Furthermore **C# code could not be used in external js file**. You could set a hidden input and set `@Url.Action()` to value.

Change your code like below:

YourJs.js:

```
function Foo() {
    var urlAction = $("#myUrl").val();
    console.log(urlAction);
}
```

View:

```
<input id="myUrl" hidden value="@Url.Action("Privacy","Home")"/>
<input type="button" value="Create" onclick="Foo()" />

@section Scripts
{
    <script src="~/js/YourJs.js"></script>
}
```

Comment: That did the trick. I think I was confused by what I saw in the console debugger how  "'@Url.Action("DeleteCompany","Company")'" was evaluated to "/Company/DeleteCompany". Thx!